# How to load items into dropdownlist after selecting item from another dropdownlist in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have four dropdownlistbox in my form, i want to load items into three dropdownlists according to the selection of items from the first drop down list , my first dropdown list has folloding items

Amount ,
PAC ,
Base UOM

Whatever i am selecting from first drop down list , i want to load the same selected item into remaining three dropdownlist

I have tried the following code but it is not working as expected

```
protected void ddl_UOM_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string uom_Name = ddl_UOM.SelectedItem.Value;
   ddl_UOM2.Items.Add(uom_Name);
   ddl_UOM3.Items.Add(uom_Name);
   ddl_UOM4.Items.Add(uom_Name);
}
```

pls help.

Comment: use cascaded dropdown of ajax control toolkit

Comment: what is not working ? Are you getting any error ?

Comment: first time it is loading to ddl but again i am selecting diffrent item from first ddl , it is ramining as same , no change is happening

Comment: Why do you have the Javascript-Tag if you dont have a Javascript code here ?

Comment: may be you are missing **AutoPostback** property. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void ddl_UOM_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string uom_Name = ddl_UOM.SelectedItem.Value;
    ddl_UOM2.Items.Clear();
    ddl_UOM3.Items.Clear();
    ddl_UOM4.Items.Clear();

    ddl_UOM2.Items.Add(uom_Name);
    ddl_UOM3.Items.Add(uom_Name);
    ddl_UOM4.Items.Add(uom_Name);


}
```

After writing code in ddl_UOM_SelectedIndexChanged() , call ddl_UOM_SelectedIndexChanged() method from Page_Load()

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         try
         {
          if (!IsPostBack)
           {
                   ddl_UOM_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e );
           }

         }
       catch (Exception)
       {

        throw;
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **Ajax Control Tool kit's Cascaded Drop-down**

Here is the like for it:

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Walkthrough/CCDWithDB.aspx

and here is the demo:

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

here is a tutorial link:

http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/ajax-cascading-dropdown-example-with-database-in-Asp-Net-1078.aspx

Hope this material helps.

Comment: cascaded dropdown is better than using javascript and sending ajax calls explicitly

Comment: in that case also @DatRid cascaded dropdown will work, he want that selected item to be added in other dropdowns.

Comment: Ah nvm, i delete my Comments, missread it, im sorry :D He should remove the Javascript tag if he hasnt tried in Javascript yet imo.

Comment: yes you are right, but if dropdown list is server side as its web forms adding items in drodown using javascript causes issue because of view state

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't have set **AutoPostBack** property to **true**. Try below code sample :

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="parentDropDown" OnSelectedIndexChanged="parentDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="child1">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="child2">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void parentDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uom_Name = parentDropDown.SelectedValue;
    child1.Items.Add(uom_Name);
    child2.Items.Add(uom_Name);
}
```

**If you want to remove existing item from child before you add then:**

```
protected void parentDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uom_Name = parentDropDown.SelectedValue;

    child1.Items.Clear();
    child2.Items.Clear();

    child1.Items.Add(uom_Name);
    child2.Items.Add(uom_Name);
}
```

Comment: @user3515164 Glad to help you. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer. so that it may help other users as well.

Comment: sorry it has some problem , the problem is when we are selectin fist item at first time when page is loading at that time it is not loading into other ddl
thanks

Comment: is there any code in your page load ? make sure that in page load if you are binding your dropdown list then it should be in **!IsPostBack**

Comment: yes I have code in my page_load @SpiderCode  i binded dropdown list and it is in !IsPostBack

Comment: make sure it is in `if(!IsPostBack){...}`

Comment: can you debug and check whether it is going in Selected Index Changed or not ? and make sure that AutoPostBack property is set to true.

Comment: i did , first time  when we select first item thenit is not going into SelectIndexChange() method but when we are selecting other items it is going

Comment: the problem was we didnot call ddl_Select-Index_Changed() method in page_Load() 
and after calling from Page_Load() method it is working now

Answer (score 0):

You have to set AutoPostBack="true" to the first drop down list and clear other drop downs items before adding new item.

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_UOM" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_UOM_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Amount" Value="Amount"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="PAC" Value="PAC"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Base" Value="Base"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_UOM2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_UOM3" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_UOM4" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**ASPX.CS**

```
protected void ddl_UOM_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string uom_Name = ddl_UOM.SelectedItem.Value;
        ddl_UOM2.Items.Clear();
        ddl_UOM2.Items.Add(new ListItem(uom_Name, uom_Name));

        ddl_UOM3.Items.Clear();
        ddl_UOM3.Items.Add(new ListItem(uom_Name, uom_Name));

        ddl_UOM4.Items.Clear();
        ddl_UOM4.Items.Add(new ListItem(uom_Name, uom_Name));
    }
```

Comment: it has some problem , the problem is when we are selectin fist item at first time when page is loading at that time it is not loading into other ddl thanks @Charbel Boutros

Comment: You have to add the code in ddl_UOM_SelectedIndexChanged into Page_Load function.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to use PageMethods in JS to load the dropdowns any way you like any time you like.

Comment: Why did you down vote this?  It's a legit answer and very powerful.